# Is it possible to block region's splitting in hbase coprocessor?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have some processing(enrichment of trades) in my coprocesserService which modifies the existing data in place. It iterates over every row, modifies and puts it back to region. The table can be modified by only one client.

During the processing size of the data is doubled-> region's size get increased -> region's split happens. It makes that the processing is stopped by exception NotServingRegionException (because region is closed and splited to two new regions so it is closed and doesn't exist anymore).

Is there any clean way to block Region's splitting for the time of processing?

I have idea to create custom RegionSplitPolicy and explicilty set some Flag which will return false in shouldSplit(), but I'm not sure yet if it is safe.

Could you advise?